# How to fix Cannot read property 'price/key' of undefined?

Tags: reactjs, redux, ecmascript-6, react-redux, state

I'm using a chrome browser and getting this error message when I'm pressing the increase button on my cart page. ][1]][1]I'm building a shopping cart using react & react-redux. But suddenly I got this TypeError where it's showing that my price key is undefined, even you can see that there is no type error the spelling was ok and I assigned a value of numbers. But when I'm clicking the increase button in my cart page it's throwing this error. How can I fix that?
       This is my cart page code:
        `import React, { Fragment } from "react";
        import { connect } from "react-redux";
        import { productQuantity } from "../actions/productQuantity";

```
    import choclateCake from "../images/cake-1.jpeg";
    import birthdayCake from "../images/cake-2.jpeg";
    import doughnut from "../images/doughnut-2.jpeg";
    import sweets from "../images/z-sweets-3.jpeg";

    const Cart = ({ basketProps, productQuantity }) => {
      console.log(basketProps);

      let productsInCart = [];

      Object.keys(basketProps.products).forEach((item) => {
        console.log(item);
        console.log(basketProps.products[item].inCart);
        if (basketProps.products[item].inCart) {
          productsInCart.push(basketProps.products[item]);
        }
        console.log(productsInCart);
      });

      // let productsImages = [cake, cake1, doughnut, sweets];
      const productsImages = (product) => {
        if (product.tagName === "choclateCake") {
          return choclateCake;
        } else if (product.tagName === "birthdayCake") {
          return birthdayCake;
        } else if (product.tagName === "doughnut") {
          return doughnut;
        } else if (product.tagName === "sweets") {
          return sweets;
        }
      };

      productsInCart = productsInCart.map((product, index) => {
        console.log("my product is", product);

        return (
          <Fragment key={index}>
            <div className="product">
              <i className="fas fa-times-circle"></i>
              <img src={productsImages[product]} />
              <span className="sm-hide">{product.name}</span>
            </div>
            <div className="price sm-hide">{product.price}tk</div>
            <div className="quantity">
              <i
                onClick={() => productQuantity("decrease", product.tagName)}
                className="fas fa-minus-circle"
              ></i>
              <span>{product.numbers}</span>
              <i
                onClick={() => productQuantity("increase", product.tagName)}
                className="fas fa-plus-circle"
              ></i>
            </div>
            <div className="total">${product.numbers * product.price}tk</div>
          </Fragment>
        );
      });

      return (
        <div className="container-products">
          <div className="product-header">
            <h5 className="product-title">PRODUCT</h5>
            <h5 className="price sm-hide">PRICE</h5>
            <h5 className="quantity">QUANTITY</h5>
            <h5 className="total">TOTAL</h5>
          </div>
          <div className="products">{productsInCart}</div>
          <div className="basketTotalContainer">
            <h4 className="basketTotalTitle">Basket Total</h4>
            <h4 className="baskeTotal">{basketProps.cartCost} tk</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    };

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
      basketProps: state.basketState,
    });

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, { productQuantity })(Cart);
    `

    This is my actiono creator file:
        `import {INCREASE_QUANTITY, DECREASE_QUANTITY } from './types'


        export const productQuantity =(action, name)=>{
            return (dispatch)=>{
                console.log('Inside product quantity');
                console.log('The action is', action);
                console.log('Prduct is', name);
                dispatch({
                    type: action === "increase" ? INCREASE_QUANTITY : DECREASE_QUANTITY,
                    payload: name
                })
            }
        }`


        `[![i'm using a chrome browser and getting this error message when I'm pressing the increase button on my cart page. ][1]][1]I'm building a shopping cart using react & react-redux. But suddenly I got this TypeError where it's showing that my price key is undefined, even you can see that there is no type error the spelling was ok and I assigned a value of numbers. But when I'm clicking the increase button in my cart page it's throwing this error. How can I fix that?
                    Thanks In advance.

                            import {
                          ADD_PRODUCT_BASKET,
                          GET_NUMBERS_BASKET,
                          INCREASE_QUANTITY,
                          DECREASE_QUANTITY,
                        } from "../actions/types";

                        const initialState = {
              basketNumbers: 0,
              cartCost: 0,
              products: {
                choclateCake: {
                  name: "Choclate Cake",
                  tagName: 'choclateCake',
                  price: 220,
                  numbers: 0,
                  inCart: false,
                },
                birthdayCake: {
                  name: "Birthday Cake",
                  tagName: 'birthdayCake',
                  price: 350,
                  numbers: 0,
                  inCart: false,
                },
                doughnut: {
                  name: "Doughnut",
                  tagName: 'doughnut',
                  price: 120,
                  numbers: 0,
                  inCart: false,
                },
                sweets: {
                  name: "Sweets",
                  tagName: 'sweets',
                  price: 100,
                  numbers: 0,
                  inCart: false,
                },
              },
            };

                        export default (state = initialState, action) => {
                          let productSelected = "";
                          switch (action.type) {
                            case ADD_PRODUCT_BASKET:
                              productSelected = { ...state.products[action.payload] };
                              productSelected.numbers += 1;
                              productSelected.inCart = true;
                              console.log(productSelected);
                              return {
                                ...state,
                                basketNumbers: state.basketNumbers + 1,
                                cartCost: state.cartCost + state.products[action.payload].price,
                                products: {
                                  ...state.products,
                                  [action.payload]: productSelected,
                                },
                              };

                            case GET_NUMBERS_BASKET:
                              return {
                                ...state,
                              };
                            case INCREASE_QUANTITY:
                              productSelected = { ...state.products[action.payload] };
                              productSelected.numbers += 1;
                              return {
                                ...state,
                                cartCost: state.cartCost + state.products[action.payload].price,
                                products: {
                                  ...state.products,
                                  [action.payload]: productSelected,
                                },
                              };
                            case DECREASE_QUANTITY:
                              productSelected = { ...state.products[action.payload] };
                              productSelected.numbers -= 1;
                              return {
                                ...state,
                                cartCost: state.cartCost - state.products[action.payload].price,
                                products: {
                                  ...state.products,
                                  [action.payload]: productSelected,
                                },
                              };
                            default:
                              return state;
                          }
                        };

                        [![I have defined the key of price in my initialState.products object and set the type of price as a number. So, why is this showing a type error and undefined][1]][1]



                          [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/10rQZ.png


                      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3Z9j.png
```

Comment: let me know what's the action.payload value when it goes to the redux reducer?

Comment: you've not shown enough relevant code. show us the `action.payload` and the action creator

Comment: Ok, I just edited my codes, now the increase button is working fine. The type error is fixed. But a new problem appeared which is my cart image is not showing. Can you see the code and why is the image is not showing?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me your `state.products[action.payload]` is `undefined`, which raises such error when you try to access a property on it.

Did you check if the action.payload values is actually valid?

Comment: Yes, I did The problem was actually in my [action.payload]. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
            So, The problem was in my [action.payload]. Here's the step that I followed and solved the problem:
            1. I changed the name of the imported image the same as my keys (products{keys:.}). Example: `import choclateCake from "../images/cake-1.jpeg";


            const productsImages = (product) => {
                    if (product.tagName === "choclateCake") {
                      return choclateCake;
                    } else if (product.tagName === "birthdayCake") {
                      return birthdayCake;
                  };

        const initialState = {
                      basketNumbers: 0,
                      cartCost: 0,
                      products: {
                        choclateCake: {
                          name: "Choclate Cake",
                          tagName: 'choclateCake',
                          price: 220,
                          numbers: 0,
                          inCart: false,
                        },
        .....

            `

    2. Then I changed the parameter of my onclick function 
`<i
                onClick={() => productQuantity("decrease", product.tagName)} //Before it was product.name. This is my action.payload
                className="fas fa-minus-circle"
              ></i>`
```

3. That's how the problem was solved